# Vimpager script: Highly mysterious

Tags: vim

I have switched my pager from `less` to `vimpager` because vim responds to the mouse wheel.

However recently after updating my vim setup by compiling a newer version of vim 7.3, and adding a series of awesome plugins, vimpager no longer does anything logical when I attempt to search text in a manpage using `n` and `N`.

This is really bad so I set out to trace the bindings back using `:verbose map`.

From the vimpager script (/usr/local/share/vim/vim73/macros/less.vim):

```
" Search
noremap <script> / H$:call <SID>Forward()<CR>/
if &wrap
  noremap <script> ? H0:call <SID>Backward()<CR>?
else
  noremap <script> ? Hg0:call <SID>Backward()<CR>?
endif

fun! s:Forward()
  " Searching forward
  noremap <script> n H$nzt<SID>L
  if &wrap
    noremap <script> N H0Nzt<SID>L
  else
    noremap <script> N Hg0Nzt<SID>L
  endif
  cnoremap <silent> <script> <CR> <CR>:cunmap <lt>CR><CR>zt<SID>L
endfun

fun! s:Backward()
  " Searching backward
  if &wrap
    noremap <script> n H0nzt<SID>L
  else
    noremap <script> n Hg0nzt<SID>L
  endif
  noremap <script> N H$Nzt<SID>L
  cnoremap <silent> <script> <CR> <CR>:cunmap <lt>CR><CR>zt<SID>L
endfun

call s:Forward()

" Quitting
noremap q :q<CR>
```

That last one I get and it makes a lot of sense. But this `H$nzt<SID>L` is completely impenetrable.

What the hell is it doing?

P.S. I've gotten my search back by turning those two functions `s:Forward()` and `s:Backward()` into empty no-op functions. So I'm all set, but what does that stuff do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the scrollwheel in `less`.

Anyway…

```
H      "puts the cursor on the first printable character 
       "of the first visible line of the window.
$      "moves the cursor to the end of that line
n      "moves the cursor on the next match
zt     "scrolls the current line at the top of the window
<SID>L "executes the L mapping defined in the current script
```

The whole thing looks like a slightly convoluted attempt to make Vim's `n` work like `less`'s `n`.

Comment: In which terminal does less respond to scrollwheel? It only does for me on Terminal.app with the MouseTerm SIMBL plugin. I dont use Terminal.app anymore because iTerm2 has keymapping and other features I like (such as italic support in latest builds)

Comment: I don't get what `H$n`'s purpose is. But thanks for going through that.

Comment: Honestly I don't get the "why" either: it looks like a workaround to me. Also I use Gnome terminal at home and iTerm at work. I know that scrollwheel works in less in Gnome terminal because I just tried it but I almost never use the mouse when doing CLI work so I'm not sure if it works in iTerm.